# unable to delete test accounts with stripe sdk

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I am writing some integration tests at the moment for my website, I have noticed that I have been creating accounts without deleting them.

I have just been deauthing them with

```
   try {
       info('deauthing: ' .$accountID);
       OAuth::deauthorize([
           'stripe_user_id' => $accountID,
       ]);
   } catch (\Stripe\Error\OAuth\OAuthBase $e) {
       exit("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
   }
```

when i try to reuse an email address for a testing account, it tells me that account already exists. But I can't see it anywhere in my dashboard.

I have tried to delete the account at the end of my test run but I get this error

```
Stripe\Error\Permission : This application is not authorized to delete this account.
```

the code i am using is this

```
   public function deleteAccount($accountID)
   {
       $account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($accountID);
       $account->delete();
   }
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to delete a Standard account via the API. As the platform you can create one, but it is then owned by a separate user and you can not control its deletion for security reasons. De-authorizing the account is the closest thing you can do in this situation.

If you're doing this for unit tests, you might want to create [Custom accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts) instead to avoid the address conflict. Otherwise, use a random suffix like my+12345@email.com